# Retrieving nested element from MongoCursor

Tags: json, scala, mongodb

I am querying a Mongo DB in Scala and looping through the returned elements, that look like this:

```
{ "_id" : "123:1350918540586068000:v" , 
    "i" : { 
        "vendorStyle" : "coolStyle" , 
        "createdAt" : 1350918540580 , 
        "productId" : "product123" , 
        "skuId" : "123"
    }
}
```

My question is: how do I retrieve the value from skuId? I know you can use the notation parent.child in the 'find' method in Mongo, but that doesn't work when reading from the resulting DBObject

This is the code:

```
val elems = SkuStorage.collection.find(MongoDBObject("i.productId" -> productId))
elems.toSeq.map { element=>
    readSkuById(element.get("i.skuId")) //breaks! 
}
```

Do I need to go get("i") then parse the string into a JSON? Is there any better way of handling this?

Comment: Have you tried calling get("i").get("skuId") ?

Comment: Yes, get("i") gives a String so you can't do .get("...") on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
element.expand[String]("i.skuId")
```

it returns `Option[String]`

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like I can't do .expand:

value expand is not a member of com.mongodb.casbah.package.DBObject

Comment: import com.mongodb.casbah.Implicits._